# Laravel Form::select change background-color

Tags: javascript, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-4

I have this select:

```
 {{ Form::select('set', $sets, $prod->set_id, array('class' => 'form-select', 'id' => 'sel')) }}
```

I want to change the background-color of this select box when I choose a option. But I don't know how I can do it. Could you help me? I think that with javascript it´s possible, but... how? I have the color in my database, one color for one option.

Comment: bootstrap javascript? no, could you give me a example please? I don't know how to do it...

Comment: Thank you for your example, but I need create a event for function onChange, not for css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

{{ Form::select(...., array('id' => 'sel'); }}
Then just the assign your id to the onChange event in your JS:

```
$(function(){
   $('sel').change(function(e) {
      document.getElementById('sel').style.color="magenta";
   });
});
```